# sql server 2017 - How to create unique values and relate columns to these

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am a newbie to SQL server but have found it extremely useful.

RIght now i am battling with a sql structure i need to rearrange.

I have a database which have 6 columns:

```
Call ID and Question1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Call ID is the person which answers the call, as 6 questions are asked, the same Call ID can exist multiple places in the Call ID column.

In order to create a list of unique Call IDs, i have made the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [call_id]
FROM [ConnectCallData_26391].[dbo].[call_events]
```

What i now need to do:

I need to use the results from the CALL ID DISCTINCT query and align the Questions 1-6 to the Call ID so the unique call id only has one row and all questions as before are listed on row 2-6 !

Help is very needed!!

Kind regards Daniel

This is the query that is used in order to separate Questions:

```
select 
      ,[menue_key]
      ,dte_start 
      ,[dte_updated]
      ,[rec_id]
      ,[call_id] 
      ,[duration_tot_sec] 
      ,iif([menue_key] ='SYS FLX HAC survey_question_1' OR [menue_key] ='SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_1',[menue_choice],'' ) as 'Hvad er din alder?'
      ,iif([menue_key] ='SYS FLX HAC survey_question_2' OR [menue_key] ='SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_2',[menue_choice],'' ) as 'Hvilket postnummer bor du i?'
      ,iif([menue_key] ='SYS FLX HAC survey_question_3' OR [menue_key] ='SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_3',[menue_choice],'' ) as 'Hvor tilfreds er du generelt med at benytte den anvendte ordning?'
      ,iif([menue_key] ='SYS FLX HAC survey_question_4' OR [menue_key] ='SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_4',[menue_choice],'' ) as 'Hvis du ikke havde den anvendte ordning til rådighed, hvad ville du så benytte som erstatning for dine rejser?'
      ,iif([menue_key] ='SYS FLX HAC survey_question_5' OR [menue_key] ='SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_5',[menue_choice],'' ) as 'Hvad er formålet med den tur du lige har bestilt?'
      ,iif([menue_key] ='SYS FLX HAC survey_question_6' OR [menue_key] ='SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_6',[menue_choice],'' )as 'Hvorfor bestiller du ikke din tur via internettet?'

  FROM [ConnectCallData_26391].[dbo].[call_events] 
  where menue_key in ('SYS FLX HAC survey_question_1','SYS FLX HAC survey_question_2', 'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_3',
  'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_4','SYS FLX HAC survey_question_5','SYS FLX HAC survey_question_6','SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_1','SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_2', 'SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_3',
  'SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_4','SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_5','SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_6')
```

Comment: show sample data and  expected result.

Comment: You shouldn't design the DB with questions as columns. A new question would need a new column.

Comment: Sounds like worst practice... throwing together "CallID" and "Question" is nearly as bad as throwing together all question results into the same column while verbosing the question ID...

Comment: Sounds like you need to spend a bit of time reading about normalization.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments, first of all, i totally agree that the design is terrible but as i am end user, i have no options to change the design. 

RDP and Tyron78 all questions are in the same column, - I used  IIF in order to separate them in to separate columns.

What i would like to create is columns for following values:

DISTINCT CALL ID  -  Q1 - Q2 - Q3 - Q4 - Q5 - Q7

I apologize for my lack of knowledge, unfortunately my SQL knowledge is only a two day course.

Comment: *I used IIF in order to separate them in to separate columns*  -  Please don't get halfway through a solution and then ask how to finish it.  Please post your original data, problem, solutions tried and desired result.  More often than not, a simpler solution to the one you have started will be possible.

Comment: Please show you desired result. Then its much easier. How is data now and how do you expect them to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pivot

```
;WITH Prepivot AS
(
    select 
          [call_id] AS Call_ID
          ,[menue_key]
          ,[menue_choice]
      FROM 
        [ConnectCallData_26391].[dbo].[call_events] 
      where 
        menue_key in (
            'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_1',
            'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_2', 
            'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_3',
            'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_4',
            'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_5',
            'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_6',
            'SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_1',
            'SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_2', 
            'SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_3',
            'SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_4',
            'SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_5',
            'SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_6')
)
SELECT
    P.*
FROM
    Prepivot AS N
    PIVOT (
        MAX(N.[menue_choice]) FOR N.[menue_key] IN (
            [SYS FLX HAC survey_question_1],
            [SYS FLX HAC survey_question_2], 
            [SYS FLX HAC survey_question_3],
            [SYS FLX HAC survey_question_4],
            [SYS FLX HAC survey_question_5],
            [SYS FLX HAC survey_question_6],
            [SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_1],
            [SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_2], 
            [SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_3],
            [SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_4],
            [SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_5],
            [SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_6])
    ) AS P
```

Or conditional aggregation:

```
select 
      [call_id] 
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN  [menue_key] = 'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_1' OR [menue_key] ='SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_1' THEN [menue_choice] END) as 'Hvad er din alder?'
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN  [menue_key] = 'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_2' OR [menue_key] ='SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_2' THEN [menue_choice] END) as 'Hvilket postnummer bor du i?'
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN  [menue_key] = 'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_3' OR [menue_key] ='SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_3' THEN [menue_choice] END) as 'Hvor tilfreds er du generelt med at benytte den anvendte ordning?'
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN  [menue_key] = 'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_4' OR [menue_key] ='SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_4' THEN [menue_choice] END) as 'Hvis du ikke havde den anvendte ordning til rådighed, hvad ville du så benytte som erstatning for dine rejser?'
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN  [menue_key] = 'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_5' OR [menue_key] ='SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_5' THEN [menue_choice] END) as 'Hvad er formålet med den tur du lige har bestilt?'
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN  [menue_key] = 'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_6' OR [menue_key] ='SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_6' THEN [menue_choice] END) as 'Hvorfor bestiller du ikke din tur via internettet?'
FROM 
    [ConnectCallData_26391].[dbo].[call_events] 
where 
    menue_key in (
        'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_1',
        'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_2', 
        'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_3',
        'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_4',
        'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_5',
        'SYS FLX HAC survey_question_6',
        'SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_1',
        'SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_2', 
        'SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_3',
        'SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_4',
        'SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_5',
        'SYS FLX Flextur survey_question_6')
GROUP BY
    [call_id]
```

Comment: Hi Ezzo, what i need is to extract and list the Unique Value from the Call ID and then align the questions related to the unique Call ID value in columns.

Comment: @bilingual You need to pivot. Adapt the 2nd example to your table. There's no need to "list the unique IDs", the pivot operation will solve that.

Comment: Hi Ezlo, i am not sure i understand you correctly, but i need the unique call IDS values listed, not as sums , im sorry if i do not understand fully but i am very new to SQL
Kind regards Daniel

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience! - i tried your conditional aggregation, but it wont group the call id, the same call id is still present up to 6 instances in the Call_id column

Comment: @bilingual you need to remove the other columns from the GROUP BY and just leave the call ID. I've edited it.

Comment: Ezlo - such a simple solution and i could not figure it out. Thanks a lot for your help Ezlo i really really appreciate it!!!

Comment: @bilingual I'm glad to help :), if it helped to solve your problem please mark as answer so the question isn't left open.